# Spritekit jump physical

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm working in IOS/spritekit where I have a sprite that rotates. The rotation works fine, but in addition I want that the sprite jumps. Therefore I added dynamic and restitution to my physicsBody of my sprite:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bigball"];
    sprite.position = location;
    sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
    sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0.7;
    SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];
    [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
```

This also works, but the sprite only jumps 2 times and then comes to a standstill, which is logical because I've added the dynamic, but I want that the sprite jumps infinitely.
Can anyone explain how I can do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
```

If the restitution property is at 1.0, its bounciness will be at the maximum level - the physics body will not lose any energy while bouncing, so it should bounce indefinitely.